# Resolve confusion between [gorm] and [go-gorm] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The tag [gorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorm) is [often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorm+go) used in questions related to [Go's GORM](https://gorm.io/index.html).

The [gorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorm) excerpt correctly reminds that:

> GORM is Grails' object relational mapping (ORM) implementation. **Don't use it for Golang GORM, use go-gorm for that.**

However we all know that tag excerpts are inconspicuous. This results in questions incorrectly tagged [go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go)+[gorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorm) or [gorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorm)+[go-gorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-gorm), which have to be edited.

Just like the tag [go-gorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-gorm) has the "go-" prefix to help disambiguate, the [gorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorm) tag might benefit from a "grails-" prefix.

As a matter of fact, [grails-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grails-orm) [exists, but is a synonym of `gorm`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gorm/synonyms).

Proposals:

1. reverse the synonym, i.e. [gorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorm) --> [grails-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grails-orm)
2. remove [gorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorm) altogether and retag questions with [grails-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grails-orm)
3. create a new tag for Grails ORM and synonymize [gorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorm) to it

I think **3** is maybe the best solution, but then it'd be best if Grails [gorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorm) followers suggested a proper name for a new tag.

Comment: It looks like [39 questions are mistagged as Go](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgorm%5D+%5Bgo%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3). If those can be retagged we can do #1 easily enough

Comment: @Machavity if Grails ORM followers are okay with it, #1 is better, as it doesn't introduce yet another tag

Comment: Cleaned and renamed, but I found there's a proposed synonym for [gorm-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorm-mysql) and it's not clear which it belongs to.

Comment: @Machavity thank you! [gorm-mysql] has 19 questions, and if I'm not mistaken was created with [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60800273/4108803), so it seems it was intended as a specialization of [go-gorm]. IMO, it's unnecessary, the question(s) could be tagged [go-gorm][mysql]

Comment: And that was what the synonym suggested. Merged that into [go-gorm]